# c# xaml project with System.Management.Automation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, powershell, automation

When adding code to project.csproj to use some PS snapin and commands from it I'm encountering an error during compilling:

**Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll**

Can it be suppressed? Or there is no way?

Include code:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try delete the reference, but if it is really necessary you should consider that the Automation library isn´t in the Global Assembly Cache then you need to reference the dll. In my computer the dll is in the path:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\

The reference in the ".csproj" should by something like:

```
<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: ye, found couple days ago that universal apps are not the proper ones for PS including project as there is no PS on smartphones )) switched to wpf... but thanks anyway )